# (What happens if the BYTE PTR [ebp+0x8] get a parameter greater than 1 byte? like 0xcdc485c1

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

So... I have this test.S file, where he gets this parameters: asm3(0xcdc485c1,0xd6bd5e88,0xe4c1548d)

the code:

````
```asm3:
      <+0>:   push   ebp
      <+1>:   mov    ebp,esp
      <+3>:   xor    eax,eax
      <+5>:   mov    ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0x8]
      <+8>:   shl    ax,0x10
      <+12>:  sub    al,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xe]
      <+15>:  add    ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xc]
      <+18>:  xor    ax,WORD PTR [ebp+0x10]
      <+22>:  nop
      <+23>:  pop    ebp
      <+24>:  ret```
````

i want to know what will happen with the 0xcdc485c1(ebp+0x8) for example, since it have more than 1 byte right? it will get just the significant byte? or it will be stored entire, and if is this, why?
And if you know too, where is this "ebp+0xe", it isn't a paremeter or is it?

Comment: Since x86 is little-endian, the byte with the same starting address as the dword `[ebp+8]` has the same value as the *least* significant byte of that doubleword. So if the doubleword value is CDC485C1h the byte value at the same starting address is C1h.

Comment: thanks, you really help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `<+3>` in the function, the stack looks like this:

```
               0  1  2  3   byte offsets
     + 0x10 | 8d 54 c1 e4 |
     + 0x0c | 88 5e bd d6 |
     + 0x08 | c1 85 c4 cd |
     + 0x04 | return      |
 ebp + 0x00 | prev. ebp   |
```

where there are five DWORDs (32-bit values) on the stack, each in the usual little-endian order.

For whatever reason, the code which follows is picking just a few bytes out of the stack, and one WORD (16 bits) -- so it is using a few parts of the three DWORD arguments.

Everything is just bytes; a byte-load instruction doesn't care how it was stored or what it "means", just what's currently there in memory.

---

FWIW: the `shl ax, 0x10` is a long-winded / obfuscated way of setting `ax` to zero.  [x86 shifts](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr) mask their count with `& 31` even if the operand-size is less than 32-bit, so narrow shifts can shift out all the bits, unlike `shl eax, 0x20` which does nothing.

Comment: thanks for the answer man, so just a quick question the ax after the shift would be 0x0000 right? so this would to zero the ax and al to?

Comment: Yes, the effect would be to zero `ax`, so yes both `ah` and `al` will be zero (`ax` being bits 15..0 of `eax`, `ah` being bits 15..8 and `al` being bits `7..0`).  The `xor eax, eax` zeroized all 32 bits of `eax`.  I have no idea what this code is intended to do, but the instructions: `mov ah,BYTE PTR [ebp+0x8]` and `shl ax,0x10` appear to be entirely redundant.  It might make more sense if the shift was `shl eax,0x10`... but I am just guessing.

Comment: yeah, actually it is just a ctf code, really don't make sense at all, i am just learning reverse engineering. I have an one last question about the sub operation. Because the `al` its 0x00 and its subtracted by 0xc1, then the result would be negative so it will return 0xc1 anyway? i am searching about it, and it seems to be this but i am not sure. thanks for the help

Comment: The `sub al,BYTE PTR [ebp+0xe]` subtracts `0xBD` _from_ `al = 0x00`, giving `al = 0x42` and `CF = 1`. [The code as given clearly has operands in "Intel Order", where (in this case and generally) the first operand is the destination and the second the source.  Just to keep everybody on their toes, there is also "AT&T Order", which is the opposite way around -- so Stay Awake !]

Comment: wait, are u sure its `0xBD`, the stack don't grow down? So the 0xe don't would be above the 0xc? because its greater? And would be bellow the `0x10`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's `0xBD`.  The stack does indeed grow downwards.  `ebp + 0x0C` is the address of byte 0 of the DWORD `0xD6BD5E88`, which is stored little-endian in memory, so byte 0 is `0x88`.   `ebp + 0x0E` is the address of byte 2 of that DWORD, which is `0xBD`.  In the diagram, addresses are increasing left to right and bottom to top -- the DWORDS are shown in little-endian order.